# Get ActorRef of a mutiple akka Actor instances by path

Tags: akka

I am creating a pool of instances of a **same Actor**
Later in my app, I want to be able to reference a specific instance of an actor "pool" by its unique path.

```
val instance1 = context.spawn(ActorA(), "actorA_1")
val instance2 = context.spawn(ActorA(), "actorA_2")
val instance3 = context.spawn(ActorA(), "actorA_3")
etc
```

This is done at the initialisation of the application and the goal is to allow any actor of the app to reference this instance *if it knows its unique path*...

I want to achieve something like that :

```
val actorRef = getActorByItsUniquePath(path) 
actorRef ! sendMessage(...)
```

I don't know if I need to use the classic Actor Api or the typed API (receptionist) and/or if I need to store the unique path (path + UID) of each Actor instance on a HashMap and retrieve this path later.

I don't find any clear direction to implement that in the doc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right path. In Classic Actors this is done by [actor selection](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/actors.html#identifying-actors-via-actor-selection) and Actor Path. Note that "unique path" potentially has to include the node in a clustered setup.

In typed Actors you would use the [Receptionist](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/typed/actor-discovery.html#receptionist) and the ServiceKey acts as your "unique path".

So, you don't need to use one API or the other: you should use classic actors or typed actors as you prefer. Just choose the discovery method (ActorPath or Receptionist) based on which API you have chosen.

However, I will add one caveat. Generally it is preferred not to do this. You are effectively exposing an implementation detail to your client. And removing some flexibility/resiliency. This is discussed here in the docs: https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/actors.html#identifying-actors-via-actor-selection under "It is always preferable to communicate with other Actors using their ActorRef instead of relying upon ActorSelection. Exceptions are:". This is not to say that you absolutely *shouldn't* do this, as the actor discovery APIs obviously exist for a reason. Just that you should "prefer" not to depending on looking up actors via unique path, and that you should have a good reason for not using something like a router instead.

EDIT TO REPLY TO COMMENT:

You say in the comment below that you will have actor instances with the same path, but this impossible. Actor paths are unique*; each instance has a unique path. It seems that you may think that the path is associated with the actor, but the path is the actor instance. [See the docs](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/general/addressing.html#what-is-an-actor-path-) and also see the section in the Classic docs about naming actors where it talks about the fact that [you must give a unique name to each instance](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/actors.html#creating-actors-with-props). If you don't explicitly give a unique name to your instance, the system will auto generate one. (e.g. /user/myactor/$1, /user/myactor/$2, ...)

If you do have a uid generated already, just specify it as the name of instance when you spawn it and you will end up with a path that looks like: `akka://my-actorsystem@mynode:port/user/parentactor/youruid` and you will be able to use that path to look it up.

You situation really isn't that unusual. This is a pretty common pattern to have many instances of the same actor, each maintaining state. This is also why I mention using a router pattern, because you have more flexibility with that design. In fact, this is also basically the pattern behind Akka Sharding. You may want to look into that as an option as well, especially if you are using clustering.

If you use a Receptionist and typed actors it's basically the exact example shown in the [Receiptionist docs](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/typed/actor-discovery.html). Every time you create a new actor instance you would register it with the Receptionist with the `register` message and your uid key. Then you just look it up later with a Find message. It's a wee bit more complicated because Receptionists don't enforce uniqueness (unlike Paths) and because you have to be aware of types (and therefore adapt response types) but that's all the Receptionist really is: a key-value store of actor instances implemented as an actor you send messages to.

*Technically, actor paths are unique to *living* actor instances. You, in theory could create an actor /user/foo, stop it, and then create a second instance with the same name. But I didn't want to complicate the above explanation as I didn't think that detail was important here.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I think what I want to achieve is a bit more complicated. I will have multiples instances of the same actor so same path but with an #UID. I am not sure I can receive a specific instance of multiple instance of the same actor. I need that because an instance will keep its own data that would differ from another instance. If it's possible I don't know how I can request the ActorRef using receptionist for example. Maybe I am trying to use akka in the wrong manner. Thanks for your help

Comment: I will reply in the answer as it is going to be to involved an answer.

Comment: thank you ! just to give an important information. I want to run it on a cluster mode so getting the reference of a remote Actor is also tricky (networking delay, etc). I am using artery, seed-nodes, typed Actor  etc But of course my path is unique per instance. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: Thanks. But that doesn't really affect anything here (except potentially increasing the value of sharding)

Comment: On second thought, maybe it does. If you know the uid, but not the node, you will not be able to look up the instance with ActorPaths. (Receptionist would still work though.)

More reason to use a router pattern or sharding. (With the router running on a singleton.)